What does it mean by "can be treated as the interface type" in TypeScript handbook?
In the handbook, it says that:

It’s important to understand that an implements clause is only a check that the class can be treated as the interface type. It doesn’t change the type of the class or its methods at all. A common source of error is to assume that an implements clause will change the class type - it doesn’t!

But I don't understand what it means by "can be treated as the interface type" when it also says "It doesn’t change the type of the class or its methods at all."
Does it mean that I need to repeat the exact same types for both the class and the interface?
They give an example where the type of s is any:
interface Checkable {
  check(name: string): boolean;
}
 
class NameChecker implements Checkable {
  check(s) {
    // Notice no error here
    return s.toLowerCase() === "ok";
  }
}


It’s just a check, not a contextual type. Yes, you need to fully annotate everything in the class. Adding an implements clause can only possibly cause an error. All it does is check to see if the class instance type is assignable to the interface being implemented.

@jcalz So implements is to ensure that it's assignable to the interface type?

class X implements Y {} checks that instances of X are assignable to Y. Y is usually an interface but it doesn’t have to be necessarily

Clause 1: Can be treated as an interface type:
Suppose you create an interface and two different classes implement it like the below:
interface Alphabet {
  x: number;
  y?: number;
}
class C implements Alphabet { //Error
  z = 0; 
}
class D implements Alphabet { 
  x= 1; 
  y = 0;
}

c gives an error because c can not be treated as something of type Alphabet. implements keyword is there to make that check and gives an error.
Playground
Clause 2: Doesn’t change the type of the class or its methods at all:
In the below example, one might (erroneously) expect c.y to be valid, albeit undefined. But that is not the case. Because The type of c is still C, it is not Alphabet.
interface Alphabet {
  x: number;
  y?: number;
}
class C implements Alphabet {
  x = 0;
}
class D implements Alphabet {
  x= 1;
  y = 0;
}
const c = new C();
const d = new D();

c.y; //Error
d.y; //No Error

Playground
And that is the confusion, the handbook warns against.

Importantly, removing implements Alphabet changes nothing for the rest of the code. You can still use C and D instances where an Alphabet is expected.

Oh, yes. As you mentioned in the comment, it clause can only possibly cause an error.. Then I guess the statement*. Because both classes D and C have successfully implemented Alphabet*` is invalid.

I have a question: "can be treated as the interface type" Is this predictable, i.e. Do I really need a compiler to tell me that there is an error? So it sounds like every property&method should be a subtype. In my case, s is of type any so it's a subtype of string?

Do I really need a compiler to tell me that there is an error? -> Yes right. Huge projects, where the interface might be one place and class in another. I guess you cannot keep checking every field to check if you have implemented it correctly in the class or not. That is the whole point of TypeScript.

any is not a subtype of string. any is your way out of TypeScript. Using any you can avoid type checking

The implements keyword in Typescript ensures structural subtyping. [1]
A class can implement an interface, and instances of that class can be treated as instances of the interface, allowing for structural subtyping.

But I don't understand what it means by "can be treated as the interface type" when it also says "It doesn’t change the type of the class or its methods at all."

It doesn’t change the type of the class or its methods unlike what inheritance does —Children now become subtypes of Parent and Parent inheritable methods now exist on Children.
All it does is that it ensures that an instance of the class can be treated as an instance of the interface iff it fulfilled everything in the contract i.e. completely implements the required fields of the interface.


In the example I provided, the code check(s) { ... } omits every type but it still (in your terms) fulfills the contract. [2]

For clarity, let me explain what the OP asks.
Consider the interface:
interface Checkable {
  check(S: Type): boolean;
}
The following classes implement the interface as follows:
class NameChecker implements Checkable {
  check(name: string): boolean
  {
    return name.toLowerCase() === "john doe";
  }
}

class AgeChecker implements Checkable {
  check(age: number): boolean
  {
    return age === 50;
  }
}
Why are the above considered "complete implementations" by the implements keyword even with the clearly different method signatures?
This is because Typescript uses structural typing to determine type compatibility. For functions this means that you don't need to have the exact same signature for the declaration and the implementation, as long as the compiler can determine the implementation to be safe to call through the declaration. All you need to worry about is function parameters and variance.

[1] Typescript already makes use of structural subtyping. All implements does is that it provides a strict check hence the use of "ensures" in the above wording.
[2] Actually it doesn’t omit every type, the type becomes any implicitly.

When I asked "Does it mean that I need to repeat the exact same types for both the class and the interface?", there was a voice in my mind saying it's no. In the example I provided, the code check(s) { ... } omits every type but it still (in your terms) fulfills the contract. Why? And the word "fulfill" is a very vague term from my perspective: it doesn't explain anything in this case.

You are not forced to only have an implementation for the method signature in the interface. You are free to overload. What matters is that the contract is fulfilled. In the example, check is overloaded with parameter s which has type any implicitly. When a value is of type any, you can access any properties of it (which will in turn be of type any), call it like a function, assign it to (or from) a value of any type, or pretty much anything else that’s syntactically legal. It won’t lead to typechecking errors hence the comment ”Notice no error here”.

Typescript uses structural typing to determine type compatibility. For functions this means that you don't need to have the exact same signature for the declaration and the implementation, as long as the compiler can determine that the implementation is safe to call through the declaration. All you need to worry about is function parameters and variance.

Are you sure that it's related to function overload here?

You don't need to have the exact same signature for the declaration and the implementation, as long as the compiler can determine that the implementation is safe to call through the declaration. All you need to worry about is function parameters and variance. You can overload if you want. You can have no methods that have matching signature with the interface. What matters is that the right method exists.

"To be treated as the interface type" means that wherever the implemented interface Checkable is required or expected in the codebase, an instance of the implementing NameChecker will perfectly satisfy that condition.
"It does not change the type of the class" in the sense that by implementing the interface, the class and its type won't be modified or specified to e.g. match the interface's methods more closely. If they match, they match. If they don't, an errors is thrown and the code won't compile.
Implementing the interface requires at least all the properties and methods of the interface to be present in the class definition as well. In that sense, yes, you'll need to repeat the same types for both. The interface will only specify the types (methods, arguments, and return type), whereas the class will have the concrete implementation of each method.
